# How to color BorderBrush of a DataGridRow and the previous one

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I created a custom control, inheriting from DataGrid.
I have the need of changing border of rows when mouse is over. Easy.

Except that if i set a BorderThick 0 1 0 1, bottom and top border stack and it looks like there are 2 height on some borders. =>[image]

To avoid that, i set a 0 0 0 1 BorderThick, and now it's become complex. 
Because i need to change the BorderBrush of the previous or next Row. And add a rectangle for the first border.

I ended up by doing this in the MouseMove and MouseLeave event in my custom control. It's working but i feel dirty :D

I kindly ask if anyone has another idea on how to do it ? Preferrably 100% xaml.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overlap the `Border`s. The following `XAML` has a `BorderThickness` of `1` and with `Margin="0,0,0,-1"` it will overlap the next one. But this wont fix the Problem entirely because the `Row` is not in the Front, therefore the `ZIndex` will be set to `1`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YOURSOURCE}" GridLinesVisibility="None">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <!-- Line at the Top and Bottom -->
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,1"/>
            <!-- Idle Color -->
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <!-- Overlap Row with negative Margin -->
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-1"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <!-- Bring to Front and change Line-Color -->
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

This will look like this:

[image: Preview XAML]

This needs some fine tuning, depending on the `BorderThickness` but i hope you get the idea of this concept.